# c# with visual studio windows form | How to search a textbox input into a file and return the search

Tags: c#, textbox, sortedlist

I am a beginner at C# and I am writing a project where I created a method for reading a txt file.
I have a a textbox with a search button. What the program must do is read the input in the textbox, search in the file method and present the matching result in a list box.
I already have some coding like this, but it returns nothing. Can anyone help me?

```
    private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] findValues = this.nameTextBox.Text.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string newline = string.Empty;
        gameListBox.Items.Clear();
        ReadIntoArray();
        string[][] games = new string[16][];

        var index = BinSrchByName(nameTextBox.Text);

        if (index != -1)
        {
            gameListBox.Items.Add(names[index] + " ==> $" + sales[index]);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data not found");

        }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to paste some lines from that text file. And what's the business of that jagged array `games` in this context? And what `ReadIntoArray();` exactly does?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following (I wrote some comments to help you understand my method):

```
    // Declare a list to hold the file lines
    List<string> FileLines = new List<string>();

    private void button_BrowseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open a file dialog
        using (OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            // Set the file dialog to show only *.txt file or all files
            openDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

            // Allow only single file selection
            openDialog.Multiselect = false;

            // Make sure the user didn't clicked the 'Cancel' button
            if (openDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Update the current file label with the filename only (not the full path)
                label_CurrentFile.Text = $"Current file: {Path.GetFileName(openDialog.FileName)}";

                // Add each line of the txt file into the list
                foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(openDialog.FileName, Encoding.UTF8))
                    FileLines.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button_DoSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the list
        list_SearchResults.Items.Clear();

        // Count the number of line so you will be able to present it on the results list later on
        int iLineNumber = 1;

        // For each item in the 'FileLines' list
        foreach (var item in FileLines)
        {
            // Check whether the current line contains the term the user typed in the searchbox
            // I'm using 'ToLower()' to ignore case
            if (item.ToLower().Contains(text_SearchTerm.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                // Create new ListViewItem to be added later on to the results list
                // Add the first column the complete line that contains the term in the searchbox
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(item);

                // Add the line number to the second column
                lvi.SubItems.Add(iLineNumber.ToString());

                // Add the ListviewItem to the results list
                list_SearchResults.Items.Add(lvi);
            }

            // Increment the line number variable
            iLineNumber++;
        }
    }
```

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn´t used your BrowseFile method because I already loaded my file. So I used your DoSearch_click method. But still returns no value.

Comment: When you load the file, how do you store it's content? Can you share the code of the file loading so I can see?

Answer (score 1):

This function receives the file path and the searched word and runs through the entire text file and returns the line where the requested word was found.

```
private string SearchText(string archivetxt, string word) {
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(archivetxt);
    while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
        string s = sr.ReadLine();
        if (s.IndexOf(word) > -1)
            return s;                
    }
    sr.Close();
    return word + " not found";
}
```